# Why can't I get the result sorted after using pagination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pagination

I am learning how to do pagination. So I got a task to use skip and limit and then on top of that sort it. I've used REST API and query parameters to pass the things required like skip limit sort.
Now, my logic gets me to skip and limit running when I hit the GET API but sorting doesn't work. Can anyone provide a workaround and also explain why mine isn't working?

Code:

```js
const getAliens = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const skip = parseInt(req.query.skip);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);
    const sort = req.query.sort;
    const sortOn = {};

    if (sort != null) {
      const key = sort.split(":")[0];
      const value = sort.split(":")[1] == "asc" ? 1 : -1;
      sortOn[key] === value;
    }

    const startIndex = (skip - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = skip * limit;

    const response = await Alien.find()
      .sort(sortOn)
      .find()
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(startIndex)
      .exec();

    return ResponseUtils.success(res, response);
  } catch (e) {
    Log.error(e);
    return ResponseUtils.error(res);
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `find` twice?

Comment: No, the issue is that I was not able to sort the collection. It's done. The error was due to variable names 'key' and 'value'. I think they are reserved keywords in JS that's why!